# Jmeter Inter thread communicator waits for an item in the queue and never stops even after the test duration is reached. Causing heap space issue

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am using inter thread communicator plugin to share data between two thread groups.

TG-1: generates an ID -> stores it in the queue name Q1
TG-2: picks an ID from queue -> does the processing

After some time when run duration of TG-1 is completed, it stops processing or storing ID in to Q1.
TG-2 processed all the data in the queue and keep on waiting for new data in the Q1. However Q1 will not have any data.
My expectation was when the run duration of TG-2 also completed. TG-2 should finish its job and exit. Why does TG-2 keep on waiting for data in Q1. This is causing the exhaustion of the heap space and test never stops. This is causing a serious issue.

How can we prevent this and any suggestion to add timeouts so that we do not wait for data in queue infinitely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add `kg.apc.jmeter.functions.FifoTimeout` property to your [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) and set the value to some reasonable timeout in seconds.
2. You can add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler to the first Thread Group to be the last Sampler there and configure it to stop all threads, the test will end when any virtual user reaches the Flow Control Action Sampler

   [image]

Comment: I have tried the first option of adding the timeout in user.properties and it does not take effect. It is not working. This is what I have added in user.properties ```kg.apc.jmeter.functions.FifoTimeout=120```